# Grease pencil strokes transparent on surfaces

Tags: grease-pencil

My Question is about the grease pencil drawn onto surfaces.
Grease pencil strokes on geometry are turning transparent and causing the geometry to also lose opacity.

I want to paint over an entire object with a drawn map over it but this prevents me from being able to draw on the back and front, top and bottom, side and other side, without seeing

[image]

all the other sides in view port.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong with the mesh to stroke application?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: cegaton, not sure how this is relevant, there are no caps in the message.

Comment: well then thank you for whatever edit you did, must have hit caps lock instead of shift but did not see that.  I do not type with caps, it is considered rude.
Aside from the forum etiquette, would you happen to have a solution for why the above problem is occurring?

Comment: I am having the same problem. More details: It happens when the line you drew on front, intersect in the view with the line you drew **behind** the cube (it needs to have a mesh between the lines). Any solutions for this?